# ggplot add ticks to each plot in a facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I'd like to display x-axis ticks on plots in the upper rows in facet_wraps. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +  facet_wrap(~ cut, scales = "fixed") +  geom_density()
```

generates this plot:

[image: Actual Plot]

I'd like to have ticks as I've drawn in on this plot:
[image: Desired Plot]

Is there a simple way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `scales = "free_x"` adds x axes to each plot:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    facet_wrap(~cut, scales = "free_x")
```

[image: plot with x axes]

However, as you can see and the syntax suggests, it also frees the limits of each plot to adjust automatically, so if you want them all to be consistent, you'll need to set them with `xlim`, `lims` or `scale_x_continuous`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    xlim(range(diamonds$carat)) + 
    # or lims(x = range(diamonds$carat))    
    # or scale_x_continuous(limits = range(diamonds$carat))
    facet_wrap(~cut, scales = "free_x")
```

[image: plot with uniform x axes]